# Switching ODE functions in Julia

Tags: julia, ode, differentialequations.jl

Fom document of DifferentialEquations package, switching between sets of ODE functions can be done using a parameter as

```
function f(du,u,p,t)
  if p==0
    du[1] = 2u[1]
  else
    du[1] = - u[1]
  end
  du[2] = -u[2]
end
```

Is this possible to use dependent variable (state variable) instead of parameter p as the switch like

```
function f(du,u,p,t)
  if (u[2]<=0 && du[2]>0)
    du[1] = 2u[1]
  else
    du[1] = - u[1]
  end
  du[2] = -u[2]
end
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible to use dependent variable (state variable) instead of parameter p as the switch like

Yes. It introduces a discontinuity, so it's not the best thing to do, but adaptivity will handle it. Sometimes performance can be improved by making a ContinuousCallback which rootfinds to that value as the condition, but then does nothing for the `affect!`. But yes, the code with the branch in it is fine.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your quick answer.